# Inspecting an Android Activity's own View hierarchy at runtime

Tags: android, view, inspection, view-hierarchy

Is it possible for an Activity to get to and inspect, ideally even modify, the entire View hierarchy for itself, without knowing IDs of all the views or special access such as instrumentation mode or rooting?

E.g. would it be possible to write some code that locates all, say, EditText instances in the Activity's View hierarchy and does something to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for an Activity to get to and inspect, ideally even modify, the entire View hierarchy for itself, without special access such as instrumentation mode or rooting?

`findViewById(android.R.id.content)` returns the `View` that hosts the content you supplied in `setContentView()`. Beyond that, try `getRootView()` (called on any `View`) to retrieve "the topmost view in the current view hierarchy".

Comment: That would seem a good approach to get me the anchor point, and then recursively traverse ViewGroups down through the hierarchy. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Sir, are you aware how is it possible to get the view hierarchy of another app within my app? It's possible, see [Developer Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsisle.developerassistant).

Comment: @azizbekian: "It's possible" -- not really. That app presumably is abusing accessibility APIs, or perhaps autofill APIs. Neither of those give you the `View` hierarchy of another app.